# How to verify that Pika 1.0.0 "basic_publish" method executes successfully

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

In Pika 0.13.1 this code worked as expected:

```
    if channel.basic_publish(exchange='exchange', routing_key='', properties=properties, body=message_as_string):
        pass
    else:
        raise RuntimeException("Fail!")
```

After upgrading to Pika 1.0.0, the "basic_publish" function don't seem to return boolean anymore, but I haven't figured out exactly what it returns (if anything), and how to verify that the function executes successfully. Based on my understanding of Pika's source code, I'm thinking basic_publish doesn't return anything but rather raises exceptions if anything happens.

Have anyone else figured out out to verify that "basic_publish" executes successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no exceptions are thrown, the publish has been sent successfully. You should consider using the mandatory flag and enabling [publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms) to be notified when your message is routed and queued by RabbitMQ. The success of the `basic_publish` function is only one part of the equation.